# Creating a connection pool in a java command line application

Tags: java, applet, database-connection, connection-pooling

Is it possible to create a command line application (without an application server) That uses a connection pool in order to access the database?. And how to do it?

I've tried it using an InitialContext object and look up for the datasource in the context but  since i don't have an application server i don't know  how to access the resource. any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/guide/jndi-howto.html shows you how

Answer (score 1):

Use a standalone connection pool library such as [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/).